# Recursively filter an array of objects according to an array of conditions

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have an array with objects that I want to filter according to an indefinite number of conditions passed as parameters.

Here's how I filter the array a with a array of conditions in hide ()

```
const statuses = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'archived'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'coming',
    hide: (...filterParam) => filterParam.every(rule => rule)
  }
];

const filteredStatuses = statuses.filter(element => {
  switch (element.id) {
    case 1:
      return !element.hide(this.isTopTabs());
    // other cases with others logic
    default:
      return true;
  }
});
```

Now if each object can have its own children object array like that:

```
const statuses = [
  {
    id: 'statuses',
    name: 'treeName',
    children: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'inProgress',
        hide: (...filterParam) => filterParam.every(Boolean)
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'coming',
        checked: false,
        hide: (...filterParam) => filterParam.every(Boolean)
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

How I can recursively iterate the same way?

Do you have a better way to filter this array dynamically by avoiding the switch / case?

And finally how to type the rest parameters with a generic like that hide: `<T>(...filterParam: Array<T>) => filterParam.every(Boolean)` ?

Comment: This is literally an exact copy of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55734423/10221765).

Comment: What's the expected output for second case, the one with children?

Comment: @JackBashford that link gives page not found error

Comment: It's deleted, >10k only @ShoyebSheikh.

Comment: @jack although "reasking" is generally unfair to the answerers, in this case there was no working answer whatsoever so I do understand the OP.

Comment: @JackBashford you mean only users with reps > 10k can see that link ?

Comment: Yes - see the [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)

Answer (score 0):

> How I can recursively iterate the same way?

```
  const filterRecursively = elements => filterStatuses(elements).map(it => ({ ...it, children: it.children && filterRecursively(it.children) }));
```

> Do you have a better way to filter this array dynamically by avoiding the switch / case?

Why? Whats wrong with the `switch` case? Isn't it fancy enough?

> And finally how to type the rest parameters with a generic like that hide: (...filterParam: Array) => filterParam.every(Boolean) ?

```
  <T>(...filterParam: Array<T>) => boolean
```

Comment: it only returns the filtered children array, not the original filtered array, is normal ?